# sort elements in group using aggregation

Tags: php, mongodb

I have these documents

```
 {
"_id": ObjectId("54de59a73674754822a1d71c"),
"date": ISODate("2015-02-13T00:00:00.0Z"),
"code1": "AAA",
"code2": "BBB",
"currency": "€",
"price": 177.6
}   

{
"_id": ObjectId("54de59a73674754822a1d71c"),
"date": ISODate("2015-02-13T00:00:00.0Z"),
"code1": "AAA",
"code2": "BBB",
"currency": "€",
"price": 90.6
}

{
"_id": ObjectId("54de59a73674754822a1d71c"),
"date": ISODate("2015-02-13T00:00:00.0Z"),
"code1": "AAA",
"code2": "BBB",
"currency": "€",
"price": 150.6
}

{
"_id": ObjectId("54de59a73674754822a1d71c"),
"date": ISODate("2015-02-13T00:00:00.0Z"),
"code1": "CCC",
"code2": "DDD",
"currency": "€",
"price": 100.6
}
```

and I want to use the aggregation framework of mongodb to group the documents by code1 and code2, in order to:
- count occurrences, and then
- use the $last operator to get the cheapest from the group.

Here is my code, it's working sorting the documents by occurrences, but $last is giving me a random document, not the cheapest from the group.

```
public function aggregateQuery(){

    $connection=  new \MongoClient('server');
    $dbname = $connection->selectDB('db');
    $collection = $dbname->selectCollection('collection');

    $parameters = array();  
    $match = array('currency' => "€");
    array_push($parameters, array('$match' => $match));

    $group_parameters = array('_id' => array('code1' => '$code1', 'code2' => '$code2'), 'price' => array('$last' =>'$price'), 'occurrences' => array('$sum' => 1));

    array_push($parameters, $array('$group' => group_parameters));
    array_push($parameters,  array('$sort' => array('occurrences' => 1)));

    return $$collection->aggregate($parameters);

}
```

I want to get as a result:
AAA - BBB : 90.6
CCC - DDD: 100.6

Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to sort your data before using `$last`. Otherwise it will be random which document is the last.

Comment: so, if I keep the code as it is, and just include this line:  `array_push($parameters,  array('$sort' => array('price' => -1)));`  it should work?

Comment: Yes. It would ensure the documents to be in the same order before entering the $group stage

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'll give you a feedback...